# Django - increase time for user to input form

Tags: python, django, iis

I inherited a Django app, I know nothing about Python or Django.

The app is a form for our internal users - only 1 person a day uses this form.

The issue is that if the user walks away for 10 minutes and clicks submit, the form submission fails.

It fails here.

```
Current_Case_NO=cache.get('Current_Case_NO')
number=Current_Case_NO.replace("'","")
```

The error is:

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

I believe the cache is expiring but I can't figure out how to handle cache settings.  I found something in the .settings file but it's not seeming to work.

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    42000

How do I control cache behavior?  This is running in Windows Server 2016 / IIS - the app uses MemCached

Comment: You can always use `try:` and `except <exceptionType>:` to retry once it fails. Apart from that I don't think there's a way of fixing it.

Comment: There is some Django doc stating this: 

Cache arguments¶
Each cache backend can be given additional arguments to control caching behavior. These arguments are provided as additional keys in the CACHES setting. Valid arguments are as follows:

TIMEOUT: The default timeout, in seconds, to use for the cache. This argument defaults to 300 seconds (5 minutes). You can set TIMEOUT to None so that, by default, cache keys never expire. A value of 0 causes keys to immediately expire (effectively “don’t cache”).

But it seems to have no effect on the problem.

Comment: Is the application reporting errors locally? Or will the error be reported only when deployed on IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I didn't give the proper info - the settings have changed from older version to newer version of Django in terms of the middleware.   I think it used to be MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and is now just MIDDLEWARE.

The second issue was that there was no database set up.  How it could even run without a database I do not know.  I installed MySQL and set that up as the Django database - this is where session info is stored to the best of my knowledge (won't claim expertise here)

So the root cause was these two things.  Once I got it done the application behaved as expected and session variables could be referenced properly.

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.